# get category url through product url

Tags: php, magento, wamp

how i can get `category url through product url`

i have product url but i want to get category `url`
[image]

**i want to redirect into category page when user click on product name**

[Site Link](http://www.washroomstudios.com/dev/products/basin-mixers/single-lever-tall-boy-with-120mm-extensi.html)

*my code is :*

```
<?php
    if($this->getItems()->getSize()):
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->load($categoryid);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 cpl-xs-12">  
            <div class="ndlSimilarTop">
                <div class="ndlSimilatProductTitle">RECOMMENDED PRODUCTS</div>
                <div id="amazingcarousel-container-1" style="overflow:hidden">
                    <div id="amazingcarousel-1" style="display:block;position:relative;width:100%;max-width:711px;margin:0px auto 0px;">
                        <div class="amazingcarousel-list-container" style="overflow:hidden;">
                            <ul class="amazingcarousel-list">
                              <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                                    <li class="amazingcarousel-item">
                                        <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
                                            <div class="amazingcarousel-image">
                                                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(217, 173) ?>"  alt="product-img" />

                                                <ul class="mask mask1">
                                                    <li class="ndlHoverContent ndlHoverContent1">
                                                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="ndlListWishlist ndlListWishlist1 ndlListWishlist2"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>images/wishlist-white-icon.png" alt="">Add to wishlist</a>
                                                        <a href="#" class="ndlListAddtobag ndlListAddtobag1 ndlListAddtobag2"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>images/mybag-white-icon.png" alt="">Add to bag</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php echo "Product Url:".$_item->getProductUrl();
                                             echo "CAT Url:".$_item->getCategoryUrl(); 
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="ndlListDetail">
                                                <div class="ndlProductListName"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: are you getiing any error with your code ?  
you can get the category url from its id like   Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id)->getUrl();

Comment: where i have to put this code

Comment: it is possible to get category url using product url ?

Answer (score 0):

One such solution can be below:

```
<?php
    $productUrlPath = 'electronics/cameras/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera.html';
    $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->loadByRequestPath($productUrlPath);
    $productId = $rewrite->getProductId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $categoriesId = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach($categoriesId as $categoryId){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        echo $category->getUrl();
    }
?>
```

**Note:** You can have more than one category of product.